# How do I add tags to certain strings in python using re.sub?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to add tags to some given query strings, and the tags should wrap around all the matching strings.
For example, I want to wrap   tags around all the words that match the query `iphone games mac` in the sentence `I love downloading iPhone games from my mac.` It should be `I love downloading <em>iPhone games</em> from my <em>mac</em>.`

Currently, I tried

```
sentence = "I love downloading iPhone games from my mac."
query = r'((iphone|games|mac)\s*)+'
regex = re.compile(query, re.I)
sentence = regex.sub(r'<em>\1</em> ', sentence)
```

The sentence outputs

```
I love downloading <em>games </em> on my <em>mac</em> !
```

Where \1 is only replace by one word (`games` instead of `iPhone games`) and there are some unnecessary spaces after the word. How do I write the regular expression to get the desired output? Thanks!

**Edit:**
I just realized that both Fred and Chris's solutions have problems when I have words within words. For instance, if my query is `game`, then it will turn out to be `<em>game</em>s` while I want it not be highlighted. Another example is `the` in `either` shouldn't be highlighted.

**Edit 2:**
I took Chris' new solution and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, to get the spaces as you want them, replace `\s*` with `\s*?` to make it non-greedy.

First fix:

```
>>> re.compile(r'(((iphone|games|mac)\s*?)+)', re.I).sub(r'<em>\1</em>', sentence)
'I love downloading <em>iPhone</em> <em>games</em> from my <em>mac</em>.'
```

Unfortunately, once the `\s*` is non-greedy, it splits phrases, as you can see. Without it, it goes like this, grouping the two together:

```
>>> re.compile(r'(((iPhone|games|mac)\s*)+)').sub(r'<em>\1</em>', sentence)
'I love downloading <em>iPhone games </em>from my <em>mac</em>.'
```

I can't think yet how to fix this.

Note also that in these I have stuck in an extra set of brackets around the + so that all matches get caught - that's the difference.

Further update: actually, I can think of a way to get around it. You decide whether you want it like that.

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'((iphone|games|mac)(\s*(iphone|games|mac))*)', re.I)
>>> regex.sub(r'<em>\1</em>', sentence)
'I love downloading <em>iPhone games</em> from my <em>mac</em>.'
```

**Update:** taking your point about word boundaries into account, we only need to add in a few instances of `\b`, the word boundary matcher.

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(\b(iphone|games|mac)\b(\s*(iphone|games|mac)\b)*)', re.I)
>>> regex.sub(r'<em>\1</em>', 'I love downloading iPhone games from my mac')
'I love downloading <em>iPhone games</em> from my <em>mac</em>'
>>> regex.sub(r'<em>\1</em>', 'I love downloading iPhone gameses from my mac')
'I love downloading <em>iPhone</em> gameses from my <em>mac</em>'
>>> regex.sub(r'<em>\1</em>', 'I love downloading iPhoney games from my mac')
'I love downloading iPhoney <em>games</em> from my <em>mac</em>'
>>> regex.sub(r'<em>\1</em>', 'I love downloading iPhoney gameses from my mac')
'I love downloading iPhoney gameses from my <em>mac</em>'
>>> regex.sub(r'<em>\1</em>', 'I love downloading miPhone gameses from my mac')
'I love downloading miPhone gameses from my <em>mac</em>'
>>> regex.sub(r'<em>\1</em>', 'I love downloading miPhone games from my mac')
'I love downloading miPhone <em>games</em> from my <em>mac</em>'
>>> regex.sub(r'<em>\1</em>', 'I love downloading iPhone igames from my mac')
'I love downloading <em>iPhone</em> igames from my <em>mac</em>'
```

Comment: True, missed that. And I suppose that's why he was using re.compile rather than re.sub - it seems that allowing `flags` in re.sub was only added in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you! the last one is perfect.

Comment: Peter, be sure to hit the check mark on the left so it specifies that you accept the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just realized that it has some problems.

Comment: @Peter: updated to include using `\b`. Same technique would apply for Fred's solution too.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'(\s*)((?:\s*\b(?:iphone|games|mac)\b)+)', re.I)
>>> r.sub(r'\1<em>\2</em>', sentence)
'I love downloading <em>iPhone games</em> from my <em>mac</em>.'
```

The extra group fully containing the plus-repetition avoids losing words, while shifting the spaces before the words — but taking out leading spaces initially — handles that problem.  The word boundary assertions require full word matching for the 3 words between them.  However, NLP is hard and there will still be cases where this doesn't work as expected.